# npm install doesn't work in Windows PowerShell

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

So my problem is this. I have a project with a package.json. When I in the command prompt (cmd.exe) run "npm install" everything installs as expected. However when I do the exact same thing in PowerShell (powershell.exe) I get an error: "npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'c:\package.json'" even though I ran "npm install" in the path of the project. It always searches for package.json in c: for some reason I can't understand.

Below is the npm-debug.log (which also is written i c: even though my path is c:\code\myProject):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.11
3 info using node@v0.10.21
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 error Error: ENOENT, open 'c:\package.json'
7 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
7 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
7 error or email it to:
7 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
8 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
9 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
10 error cwd c:\
11 error node -v v0.10.21
12 error npm -v 1.3.11
13 error path c:\package.json
14 error code ENOENT
15 error errno 34
16 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

I can't find a solution to this problem anywhere. The PATH variable is setup correctly since both node and npm itself works.

Comment: I don't know node.js, but if it searches packages based on source path, the double \\ before node.exe may be the issue. HTH

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `.npmrc` to set the prefix explicitly:

- Go to `\Users\%USERNAME%\.npmrc`. For example, in Powershell:

  ```
  Notepad "\Users\$env:USERNAME\.npmrc"
  ```
- Set the prefix:

  ```
  prefix = "C:/Program Files/nodejs"
  ```

**References**

- [Is there a manual install of node.js for Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504309/1113772)
- [Opening a program with PowerShell from a shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807603/1113772)
- [nodeJS Modules: Loading from the Global Folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)
- [npm config Readme](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config)
- [npm Folders: prefix configuration](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#prefix-configuration)
- [nodejs source: legacy-npm-self-install.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/npm/test/tap/legacy-npm-self-install.js)
- [forward slash usage](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7312)

Comment: If you have a NODE_HOME environment variable you can also use `"${NODE_HOME}"`

Comment: I opened the location. There was no hidden .npmrc file. I created one in VScode. But I searched and found .npmrc at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\. It was empty, but there's a npmrc.txt file with this prefix=${APPDATA}\npm. I don't know if I could use that. I tried the NODE_HOME env var. Nothing in any case (each timer closing & reopening admin pwsh. . What am I missing? The npm help config files were mind-boggling.

Comment: Sorry, I waited too long to edit my comment. I found that you can't change the config prefix from the project config. So, that attempt was a mistake from the start. I think I have to create the .npmrc file in the original \Users\%USERNAME%\ location.

Answer (score 25):

For me, it was much easier to do this in Powershell.

```
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files\nodejs\"
```

Ran "npm" in powershell, and came up straight away.

Comment: This won't set it permanently. A new shell won't have the environment path linked to node

Comment: THANK YOU. Literally this was driving me crazy. Don't know why the guides for node/npm aren't better about updating the path so you can use it in Powershell.