# npm always using home directory as current working directory

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

npm insists on using my home directory as the current working directory, no matter which directory I am executing commands from.

Happens with both cmd and Powershell, I've tried removing and reinstalling node, both using the installer on nodejs.org, and via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) with the same result.

If I navigate to e.g. `C:\test` and run `npm init`, the wizard places the resulting `package.json` file in my home folder.

If I run `npm install <package>` from any folder, the package is installed to `C:\Users\myusername\node_modules`

Trying to install a package globally also fails, with this

```
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\nodejs.commandline.0.10.33\\tools\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\npm.1.4.9\\tools\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\<myusername>
```

If I navigate to a folder, start the node REPL and run `process.cwd()` the directory I started node from is returned, so the issue seems to be limited to npm.

Running `npm get` gives this result:

```
C:\test> npm get
; cli configs
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
user-agent = "npm/1.4.9 node/v0.10.33 win32 x64"

; node bin location = C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs.commandline.0.10.33\tools\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\<myusername>
; HOME = C:\Users\<myusername>
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

I've searched quite a bit for a solution, and have found some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569990/npm-install-doesnt-work-in-windows-powershell) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920571/cant-install-any-packages-in-node-js-using-npm-install?rq=1), but none that solved my problem. I know that npm walks up the directory tree to look for a node_modules folder, but this happens in folders outside my home directory as well.

Any tips on what I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I had a `cd C:\Users\<myusername>` command in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` in the registry. Meaning that this command was executed any time `CMD.EXE` started.

No idea how that got in there, I might have added it myself at some point.

Anyway, if someone experiences differences between the current working directory when executing a script and when running the same command manually in an open command prompt, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`are good places to check.

Comment: This gave me so much frustration it probably took 5 years of my life.. THANKS! Any idea how such a tricky oneliner could get there?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think you'll get this if when you don't have a package.json file. Try to create one (npm init) then try installing any modules. Should then save them under node_modules of whatever current directory you're in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but like I mentioned, `npm init` creates the `package.json` file in my home folder, no matter where I run it from.
Creating a `package.json` file manually in another folder outside my home folder, and then running e.g. `npm install gulp` from that folder, still creates a new `node_modules` folder in my home folder, and installs gulp there instead.