# nodemon looking for file in C drive instead of project directory.

Tags: .net, node.js, angular, nodemon

I'm using nodemon to monitor my file changes. I have a custom script in my package.json script section as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --ignore htm,html --ext cs,js --exec \"dotnet run --debug\" -V"
  }
```

which I run by opening a command prompt at the same location as my package.json file and running `npm run start`. When I run that command, I get the following error:

```
The current project is not valid because of the folloding errors:
C:\<1,0>: error: DOTNET1017: Project file does not exist 'C:\project.json'.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm not sure why it is looking in the C drive. This started happening when I started using a new development computer - my old dev machine never had this issue. I've checked my node, npm, and nodemon versions between both computers and they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the current project entry point in the command (or `./` if the defaults work):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --ignore htm,html --ext cs,js --exec \"dotnet run --debug\" -V ./server.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, see this SO post (turns out there was a registry value that changed the current working directory) : [npm always using home directory as current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026014/npm-always-using-home-directory-as-current-working-directory)