# How to correctly configure Windows PATH environment variable for Node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell, environment-variables, nodemon

I have installed globally the *nodemon* module (version 1.11.0).

The installation was successful and the package exists in the global modules list, but the *nodemon* command returns the following error in Powershell:

```
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This happens when I try to run commands from other globally installed modules, so It seems there is a path error.

The user variable with name *PATH* has the value:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Cal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
```

Is my diagnosis correct, and if so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which of those paths holds the nodemon executable? Does browsing to the path and running nodemon work? Does running `. nodemon` and `& nodemon` give the same result?

Comment: I tried both commands on both paths and the error from the OP was returned in each case.

The nodemon directory is located at the C:\Users\Cal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules path.

Comment: Does this command work: `. C:\Users\Cal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon`

Comment: what is the command that you are trying? Post it as a whole.

Comment: After the `Path` variable is updated in the registry, this change is not reflected to open PowerShell instances. You will have to close and reopen your PowerShell instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install doesn't work in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569990/npm-install-doesnt-work-in-windows-powershell)

Comment: Try to add to your path `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm` without the trailing `node_modules`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007252/the-term-msbot-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-fil), it worked for me like a charm.

Comment: I can confirm that @twglomski 's solution works on Windows 10!

Simply add a new system variable: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon`

Where {username} is the account name of your computer.

Then **restart** your console/IDE and retry the command.