# The term 'msbot' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, botframework

Even after running "npm install -g msbot", I still see msbot : The term 'msbot' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again when tring to clear existing secrets and decrypt use this:

msbot secret -b my.bot --secret OLDSECRET --clear

Comment: had to add path in front of msbot command

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the steps for updating environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by a few things. Here's a few troubleshooting steps you can try:

1. If your console is running inside of Visual Studio or VS Code, try running it from a normal console.
2. If you just installed `msbot`, you may need to close and re-open your console.
3. Ensure that your `npm` folder has been added to your Environment Variables.See "Adding Environment Variables" below.
4. If you already have the `PATH` variable added from step 3, you may need to move that entry to ensure it is *above/before* your Node install path (`%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\`)

#### Adding Environment Variable

1. Start Menu > Type "environment variables" and hit Enter

[image]

2. Click Environment Variables

[image]

3. Double-click Path

[image]

4. Ensure `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm` (or your npm install path) has been added to your PATH variable. You may need to restart your computer for this to take effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realized that after posting the question