# i am trying to run the command npm install in visual code but it is showing me this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

[

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\sahib\Downloads\generative-art-node-main (1)> npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\sahib/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sahib\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sahib\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-14T13_21_21_398Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\sahib\Downloads\generative-art-node-main (1)> ][1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install doesn't work in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569990/npm-install-doesnt-work-in-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `npm install` from the folder that contains `package.json`. Verify this by running a `ls` command and see if the package.json is listed in the output

You typed

```
PS C:\Users\sahib\Downloads\generative-art-node-main (1)> npm install
```

but the error is looking for something two directories up:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\sahib\package.json'
```

This would indicate something weird/wrong in the package.json you're trying to install.

Comment: can you be more specific please \

Comment: The error is looking for package.json in C:\Users\sahib  -- do you have something weird in the package.json that is referencing "../.." in that package.json?